# How to insert to mysql database with ěšč or ů

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

I've got one problem, that command INSERT in C# (.net connector) inserts all characters except these:

> ěščů.

When I write this chars into the TextBox and click add (which start command INSERT), but `ř will be r`, `č -> c`, `ě -> e` and `ů -> u`.

These chars are in charset windows-1250 (Czech collate, but default collate has it too). I tried this command in query before command INSERT is called.

```
set charset cp1250;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off, in the long run, with utf8.  However, the rest of my answer applies to either cp1250, latin2, or utf8.

1. Identify which encoding your Textbox is using.  If that is part of a web page, the  tag at the top of the page, if present, says.  If it is missing, you need it.
2. Perform the C# equivalent of `set_charset` or `SET NAMES`.  Use the same encoding as you found in step 1.
3. Establish the columns in your database to have some `CHARACTER SET` other than the old default of `latin1`.  Any of the 3 mentioned should work.  It does not have to be the same as steps 1 and 2; MySQL will transcode as data flows between the client and server.
4. Once you have data in your table(s), do `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` to see what got stored.  For `č`, the utf8 is 2 bytes, in hex: `C4 8D`; for latin2 or cp1250, it is one byte: `E8`;

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250), cp1250 should work for Polish, Czech, Slovak, Hungarian, Slovene, Bosnian, Croatian, Serbian (Latin script), Romanian (before 1993 spelling reform) and Albanian.  utf8mb4 works for the whole world.